# Rails Blacklight SOLR Highlighting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, highlight, blacklight

Anyone able to get the highlighting feature to work on the actual documents views?  Anytime I add highlight: true like the code below then the field is removed from the show page??

```rb
config.add_show_field 'description', label: 'Description', highlight: true
```

Answer (score 1):

The `highlight` option is for `add_index_field` not `add_show_field`. See https://github.com/projectblacklight/blacklight/wiki/Blacklight-configuration#solr-hit-highlighting